# Installing Fspy into Blender 2.83 issues

Tags: fspy

I have downloaded Fspy zip file, not unpacked it gone to add-ons and installed but Fspy is not showing in my Import-Export

[image: locating zip file]

[image: import-export: Fspy Project not showing]

I must be missing a step, any advice.

Comment: Look in the import-export section. The instructions on how to install fspy are quite clear in the github page https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender

Comment: Susu, Thank you for taking the time to reply to my problem.  I have followed all procedures as described in instructions, but Fspy fails to go into add-ons.

Comment: use the filters at the top of the preferences window to show only the import-export addons https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cfUE.png also check for errors on the console/terminal